# I'm getting error in room database , :app:kaptDebugKotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-extension

I got this error when I used the room database

Error:

> Entity class must be annotated with @Entity - androidx.room.Entity

Error: Entities and POJOs must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type). - androidx.room.Entity

Error:

> An entity must have at least 1 field annotated with @PrimaryKey -
> androidx.room.Entity

Error:

> [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near ")": syntax
> error) - androidx.room.Entity

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.todolist"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0'

    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4")

    //room
     def    room_version = '2.4.3'
    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version")
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version")
```

still facing issues

// this is my entity class

```
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey

@Entity(tableName = "To_do")
data class Entity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int,
    var title: String,
    var priority: String

    )
```

Comment: Could you include your Entity class (and maybe other room related classes?)

Comment: @JustSightseeing     import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey

@Entity(tableName = "To_do")
data class Entity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int,
    var title: String,
    var priority: String

    )

Comment: Are those all of your room files? don't you have a data access object or maybe a repository?

Comment: @JustSightseeing I can share u my whole code can u plzz help me with that . It's all complete just check the error